# Can we cast object into integer so that it can be used as index in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, z3py

I was trying to use `X[i][j]` as an index but I am getting this error:

> TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index.

Can we cast object into integer so that it can be used as index?

My code:
I was creating z3py constraint:

```
z_c = [Z[i][j] == Y[i][X[i][j]] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
```

Comment: I think the error is probably because of `Y[i][...]` since `X[i][j]` is probably not an `int`. What kind of object is `X[i][j]`?

Comment: You've provided so little info to figure out what's going on. But perhaps the following discussion might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708500/how-to-declare-constraints-with-variable-as-array-index-in-z3py